# What's the etymology of "harelip"?

Tags: etymology

I know it's no longer used much, having been replaced by the more clinical "cleft lip".

The spelling makes me suspect it's named for the animal, as rabbits have a similar feature on their faces, but couldn't find any decent evidence thereof.

Comment: [See origin here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/harelip)

Comment: @Mitch There seems to be inadequate background effort. I vote to close as GR.

Comment: @Kris, this is an OUTRAGE. Okay, it's not.  FWIW, I *did* search first, but I was on mobile, so while my Google string failed to turn up the answer, I agree that it was pretty findable if I'd simply gone to one or two top references. While I do think this site currently has too many GR sources to realistically expect someone to review them all prior to asking, clearly one or two canonical dictionaries would be reasonable, and this was findable there, so this would be OT regardless.  Fair closure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the OED, it is:

> Fissure of the upper lip, caused by the arrest of development in the upper lip or jaw; **so called from the resemblance to the cleft lip of a hare.**

Comment: That shows the question is GR.